# ABN Lookup with simplehtmldom

Tags: simple-html-dom

I'm trying to retrieve ABN details for a given ABN Number through the ABN Lookup tool and Simple HTML DOM (http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) so for a given ABN number like 12928238010:

Scrape URL https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?id=12928238010

Selector:

```
content > div > form > div > table > tbody(2) > td:nth-child(1) > a
```

[image: ABN DETAILS 12928238010]

But I'm just after the business/es name/s itself and

```
content > div > form > div > table > tbody(2) > td:nth-child(1) > a > text
```

is not giving the expected result.

Comment: Instead of scraping, why not use the [ABN Lookup Web Service](https://abr.business.gov.au/Documentation/Default)?

Comment: great, didn't know that exist!